# Viewengine using a static class on controller view method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working on themes at present and the  majority of work is going well am just at the phase where I am figuring out what view to present to the user.

This would be on a controller method so far I have.

```
public static class ThemeViewExtensions
{

  public static string GetViewPath(RazorView view , string viewName = "Default")
  {
        var theme = "Default";

        var themeViewPath = $"/Themes/{theme}{view.ViewPath}/{viewName}.cshtml";

        return viewPath;
    }
 }
```

But for some reason I cannot access it here yes I have my using statement in

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
   return View(this.GetViewPath());
}
```

What I want to happen is to be able to use it as above and be able to get the ViewPath and name that is being called for example /Controller/Action/ViewName whatever cshtml is that possible on a view?

Comment: A controller uses a deserialize method to parse the body of a received message (either the request at the server or the response at the client).  The results of the deserilize is a class object called IActionResult.  The path I believe is taken from the HTTP headers in the receive message.  so I think it is possible.

Comment: Might u no how one would implement it i no allot people use view engines but am not wanting that complexity Just want people to be able to change views in the themes not code behind? @jdweng

Comment: If you are trying to make your method an extension method, you need to add `this` to the first argument.  `GetViewPath(this RazorView view, ...`

Comment: That is not all the problem but thank u for advice